# What distribution function $F$ is such that if $\{ X_i \}_{i=1}^{N} \sim F$, then $X_1 + ... + X_N$ is most nearly exponential?

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution

For what distribution $F$ is $X_1 + \dots + X_N$ most nearly exponential,
$X_i$ i.i.d. ~ $F$,
for $N$ = 2, 4, 8, 16 ?
How would one go about solving problems of this kind numerically ?
("Most nearly" means some metric on distributions,
of which there seem to be many;
$\mathbb{E}( X - Y )^2$ ?)

Comment: Note that this requires $N$ to be fixed in advance.  Otherwise you start to face the consequences of the central limit theorem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good place to start would be the moment-generating function (MGF), or the characteristic function, depending on your sophistication. You want to find an MGF $\phi(t) = \mathbb E e^{t X}$ such that $(\phi(t))^n \approx (1−\theta t)^{−1}$ (where $\theta$ is the scale parameter).

So, then, why not try $\phi(t)=(1-\theta t)^{-\frac{1}{n}}$? This is the MGF for a $\mathrm{Gamma}(\frac{1}{n},\theta)$ RV, and by a well known result, the sum of independent gammas with $\alpha_i$ and the same parameter $\theta$ is a gamma with $\sum_i \alpha_i$ and $\theta$.

So, choose your parameter $\theta$ you want for your exponential, choose $n$, then generate $n$ $\mathrm{Gamma}(\frac{1}{n},\theta)$ RVs. The sum will be *exactly* exponential, rather than "close" as you describe.

Comment: (+1) Good answer. You don't even have to appeal to a "well-known result" regarding the sum of (independent!) gammas. You've practically shown it (as long as you're willing to believe the more general result that a distribution is characterized by its moment-generating function, when it exists).

Comment: It may also be interesting and important to point out that this trick is slick, but will not work in full generality. A nice, moderately challenging exercise is to show that one cannot generate a $\mathcal U(0,1)$ as a sum of two iid random variables.

Comment: Great comment, cardinal. In general, the sum of two IID RV's will not follow the same distribution as the original RV's, the gamma (with the same $\theta$) and the Gaussian distribution are two special cases where it works.

Comment: Thanks Gschneider, thanks cardinal. Are there numerical methods for arbitrary distributions, e.g. best approximation to $X_1 + X_2 \sim U(0,1)$ ?

Comment: @Gschneider: Yes, though my comment was perhaps a little stronger than you may have interpreted it. What the comment was intended to say was that one can show that there is *no* distribution $F$ such that if $X_1, X_2 \sim F$ are independent, then $X_1 + X_2 \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$. :)

Comment: @cardinal, this is of course the technically perfect answer, but simulating $Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ with $\alpha<1$ is a total numerical nightmare.

Comment: @StasK: Indeed. I believe [Luc Devroye](http://luc.devroye.org/rng.html) is still offering an open bounty (of Belgian beer) for a [one-line algorithm](http://luc.devroye.org/wsc96.ps) for generating gamma random variates. I'd be curious to know if simulation is the intended interest here, or something else. :)

Comment: @cardinal, You're right, I misinterpreted what you meant, but great point